# Limited number of tries to a simple game?

Tags: java, boolean, java.util.scanner

How would I limit the tries of a simple game to just three? I would think you would use a boolean. But not sure.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class guess {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int randomN = (int) (Math.random() * 10) + 1;

        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        int guess;
        System.out.println("Enter a number between 1 and 10.");
        System.out.println();

        do {
            System.out.print("Enter your guess: ");
            guess = input.nextInt();

            if (guess == randomN) {
                System.out.println("You won!");
            } else if (guess > randomN) {
                System.out.println("Too high");
            } else if (guess < randomN) {
                System.out.println("Too low");
            } 
        } while (guess != randomN);
    }
}
```

Comment: You need a counter for the number tries that have been made, you need to increment the counter on each iteration of the loop and you need to add an additional exit condition to your `do-while` loop

Answer (score 1):

```
int attempts = 0;
do{
   attempts++;
   ....
}while(guess != randomN && attempts < 3);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a flag. Initialize it as 0. If guess is correct then reset it as 0. If not increase by 1. Before each guess, check if flag > 2. If no let continue, if yes break.

Answer (score -1):

You can increment during the failure of a guess. I believe the variable should be located outside of the loop. Then what's left is to add a portion that notifies the user of a failure when guesses run out.

```
public static void main(String[]args) {
    int rNumber = (int)(Math.random() * 10) + 1;
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    int guess;
    int tries = 0;
    int success = 0;

    System.out.println("Enter a number between 1 and 10.");
    System.out.println();
    do {
        System.out.println("Enter your guess: ");
        guess = input.nextInt();
        if(guess == rNumber) {
            System.out.println("You guessed right! You win!");
            success++;
        } else if (guess < rNumber) {
            System.out.println("Too low");
            tries++;
        } else if (guess > rNumber) {
            System.out.println("Too high.");
            tries++;
        }
    } while(tries != 3 && success != 1 || success != 1);

}
```